# I am unable to install django registration

Tags: django, django-registration

i tried installing django registration:
http://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
but i get an error: no module named registration

whenever i load my site.

what can I do?

Comment: You did the below ans right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list :

> Begin by adding registration to the INSTALLED_APPS setting of your
>   project, and specifying one additional setting:
>
> ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS This is the number of days users will have to
>   activate their accounts after registering. If a user does not activate
>   within that period, the account will remain permanently inactive and
>   may be deleted by maintenance scripts provided in django-registration.

This is from the required settings section :
http://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#required-settings

Answer (score 0):

So these are the steps that worked for me.

1. Install using pip

   $pip install django-registration
2. Make sure the django-registration is installed.

   $pip list

django-registration should show up.

1. Add 'django-registration' to INSTALLED_APPS tuple

Hope this helps.